# hook_nodeapi is not working in D8

Tags: nodes, 8, hooks

As per the api the **`hook_nodeapi`** should be called before saving the node .But its not calling the function at all when i try to save the node . How could i solve this ?

```
/**
 * hook_nodeapi, this function used to intercept the node before doing any
 * action on it
 * 
 */
function module_name_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) { 
    echo 'in hook_nodeapi';exit;
    call_fn_on_save($node, $op);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hook_nodeapi` was in Drupal 6 (which is not supported now) and has been removed starting from Drupal 7. In Drupal 8, if you want to do something when Node/Entity has been created/updated you can check respective `hook_entity_[HOOK]` or `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_[HOOK]` provided by Entity API. A complete list of all hooks provided by Entity API in Drupal 8 Core can be accessed [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/8.2.x).

Comment: Its not callling to **function module_name_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    die($entity->id());
}** also , I tried it

Comment: And **function module_name_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    die($entity->id());
}** not working too

Comment: Did you tried re-building cache after implementing this hook?

Comment: thanks , its now okay i guess :) I cleared the cache , But only entity_presave worked , entity_update not worked

Comment: `hook_entity_presave` is called before entity is created or updated, whereas `hook_entity_update` is only called when entity is updated.

Comment: Which should i rely on based on my condition ? I need to execute it before saving a node (New & Existing)

Comment: `hook_entity_presave` is what you are looking for.